# My user files are gone

Tags: updates, 22.04, files

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop version. After the System performed an update in the background I can not see all my files anymore. The Directories are all empty. Are they really gone? How can I get them back. This is really very bad there are files I really need.

Comment: Do you remember the directory where your files are located? Desktop? Documents?

Comment: Did you create a separate Home partition by any chance when you installed Ubuntu? Can you add a screenshot of the Files app? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1460912/edit) and add all the information we ask in the comments.

Comment: "This is really very bad there are files I really need." If files are important you have a backup so restore that. I have never seen an update delete files that are personal. Ever. And I would assume we ALL got the problem if it happends. Mind adding the results of `history` to the question?